# ARM Cortex-M interrupt handler in C++

Tags: c++, c, arm, interrupt-handling, cortex-m

Is it possible to write an interrupt handler in C++ for ARM Cortex chips like those of ST and NXP.

Currently I develop a lot of code in C++ for ARM cortex chips. I am a bit fed up with having to call a static/global/singleton C++ object from a C callback function. Is there a way to not having to through the C function.

Is there a way to directly call a C++ object functions when a interrupt occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to write the interrupt handler in any language that compiles to native code.

It still has to use C language linkage with the interrupt handler calling convention.  That means no member functions.  (Formally, static member functions are illegal as well, although they usually work in practice.  Non-static member functions cannot be used.)

In C++, first enable the C language linkage with `extern "C"`.  Also use any compiler-specific keyword for interrupt handlers that you would have used in C, such as `__interrupt`.

Inside the function you can use the full power of C++ -- objects, for-in loops, smart pointers, template instances, etc.  Although you still want to be careful about how much work you do in interrupt context, and C++ tends to hide the complexity so you no longer have a feel for how many machine instructions are being generated.

---

On ARM Cortex M chips, there's a table of function pointers at a preset memory address.  The table may be constructed in C or assembly, and if your interrupt handlers aren't exported with the correct name, the linker won't be able to find the addresses that belong in the table.  C language linkage ensures that any name mangling is performed in a way compatible with the symbol references in the startup code.

Other processor families use a fixed address only for the reset vector, and install other interrupt handlers by writing each handler address into a special-function register corresponding to its interrupt.  For these, only calling convention matters and not the function name/linkage.  ARM Cortex-M lets you write a special function register to find the whole vector table at an alternate address, but not to relocate individual handlers.

Comment: May I summarize your answer to: no it is not possible due to the requirement to use the C calling convention?

If so that raises another question, why are we bound to this convention?

Comment: @Bart: Hard to summarize because you had multiple questions.  Your first one "Is it possible to write an interrupt handler in C++ for ARM Cortex chips?" the answer is Yes.  For "Is there a way to not having to forward through the C function?" also Yes.  For "Is there a way to directly call a C++ object function when a interrupt occurs?" No.  There are multiple things that "C++ object function" could mean and none of them are usable as interrupt handlers.

Comment: @Bart: And as for why you are bound to this convention, it's because it is baked into the hardware.  The processor doesn't know about `this` pointers or anything like that.  In fact, interrupt handlers might not even use the C calling convention used for other functions, you might get a special calling convention by using a keyword (for example `__interrupt`, so in C++ you end up with `extern "C" __interrupt void whatever(void)`).  (The spelling of the keyword depends on your compiler)  The compiler will take care of this detail.  What it can't do is create a `this` pointer out of thin air.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I understand what you mean. By using a singleton or global object I implicitly stopped using this, hence working around that problem.

Comment: @old_timer: Can you check if my edit is precise enough to avoid confusion?

Comment: C compilers can chose their own convention there are no rules to stop them.  they can choose to use a common or recommended one or go their own way.  For the cortex-m to be able to have a c function label address in the vector table and have it work that compiler needs to conform to the convention "baked" into the logic.  otherwise C wont work either.   You can then use the traditional approach of wrapping your C function either with compiler specific features or on your own in assembly.

Comment: @old_timer: Yes absolutely you can write the interrupt handler (or a forwarder) in assembly if you choose, giving it the expected name.  You can choose your own symbol names for handler functions if you write your own (or modify) the platform support code.  But most people will use the compiler-provided startup function so they get globals correctly initialized, etc before `main()` is called.  And in that common case the interrupt handlers need to use the names designated by the platform support library, which have C linkage.

Comment: and most people are using gnu or kiel or some other that uses a compatible calling convention.

Comment: the reset vector is a special case even for C but definitely for C++ the other vectors are the one you want to use this cortex-m feature for.

Comment: I think something important is mentioned here: it is compiler dependent. In the mean time I found this link to the [IAR](https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/compiler/cortex-m-interrupt-vector-in-c-ewarm-6.21/) website. It is an example for an interrupt vertor table in C++. I did look at it but have to undertand it yet.

Answer (score 2):

> Is away to directly call a C++ object function when a interrupt occurs?

In a short, no. Even if you declare your non-static method as `void (void)`, it still has an implicit argument - `this`. Interrupt handler on the other hand, has no arguments at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand what you mean. Only a static function of that class would be a valid candidate.